# How can I open a bitmap file , change it and then save it?

Tags: c#, image, gdi+

I am trying to open a bitmap file and then change it and save it, but I am getting some error. The code is as follow:

```
var tempFileNamePath = Path.Combine(workingDirectory, fileName);
Bitmap image = new Bitmap(tempFileNamePath);
var newImage = (Bitmap)image.Clone();
image.Dispose();

newImage.EnhanceImage();
newImage.Save(tempFileNamePath, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
newImage.Dispose();
```

But it fails to save the file with error: A generic error happens in GDI+

Any thought of why tis is happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bitmap.Clone() doesn't do what you hope it does.  It is a *shallow* copy, it still uses the pixel data of the original image.  So disposing the original image doesn't release the lock on the file.

To get a *deep* copy use the Bitmap(Image) constructor:

```
Bitmap newImage = null;
using (var image = new Bitmap(tempFileNamePath)) {
    newImage = new Bitmap(image);
}
```

Renaming the original file would be cheap alternative that uses less memory, favor this when the image is large:

```
newImage.EnhanceImage();
var tmpname = tempFileNamePath + ".bak";
System.IO.File.Delete(tmpname);
System.IO.File.Move(tempFileNamePath, tmpname);
try {
    newImage.Save(tempFileNamePath, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
}
catch {
    System.IO.File.Move(tmpname, tempFileNamePath);
    throw;
}
finally {
    newImage.Dispose();
}
System.IO.File.Delete(tmpname);
```

Comment: Thanks. The rename trick doesn't work as I want to do some image processing on images and then save them.